# Ui tool with Visual Studio C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, user-interface

I'm developing a c++ tool but I need to create a form for the GUI.
I have seen some tutorials about but when I go to /Project/Add/New Item/ 
I don't have the UI section where I can find the form to add to my project.
How can I do it?

Comment: For VS your choices are stark since C++ has no idea about GUIs. MFC is the old, native code standby but more modern ones are things like Qt, Widgets and such that aren't part of VS but fairly easily imported. If you haven't ever done a C++ GUI in VS you are probably better off doing it in C# and using interop to talk to the C++ code. That's a simpler process.

Answer (score 0):

A Win32 console application has no GUI by default and runs in a console window from the command line.   [Microsoft Foundation Classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/mfc-desktop-applications?view=vs-2019) is an object oriented wrapper over the Win32 API that provides designers and extensive code-generation support for creating a native UI.I suggest you could refer to the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/user-interface-elements-mfc?view=vs-2019)

First of all, you need to create an MFC project. And then you could go to /Project/Add/New Item/UI. As shown below:

[image]